# Wrong class name after fixing missing @XmlRootElement issue

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have xsd, that is using famous convention:

```
<xsd:element name="name" type="Type">
<!-- ... -->
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="Type">
<!-- ... -->
<xsd:complexType/>
```

And because of that, when I generate classes with xjc tool I don't have @XmlRootElement annotation.
I found a solution on the stackoverflow, that is using simple binding for xjc:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
   <jxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:simple/>
   </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

when I generate classes with xjc with -extension -b flags, I've got XmlRootElement annotation. The problem is, that name of the class is no longer correct. I expect to have class "Type" that is using "" as a root element. But I receive class "Name".

I've spent almost 2 days on this issue...

Is there any way to create class with proper name and XmlRootElement annotation?

Answer (score 1):

**Using the `xjc:simple` Extension**

The generated class name isn't incorrect, it is just that the class name was derived from the global element rather than the complex type.

**Standard Behaviour**

Without the `xjc:simple` extension global elements that correspond to named complex types will have a corresponding `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on the `ObjectFactory` class.  As a result the object will be wrapped in an instance of `JAXBElement` during marshalling and unmarshalling.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/487943/1060407/#msg_1060407

Comment: Your soultion is not working as I expect - xjc generates class Name and class Type which extends class Name.